# Referring newly created column in Dask data frame operations

Tags: python, pandas, dask

```
ddf['tx_code'] = ddf.apply(setTxCode,axis=1)

ddf = ddf.groupby(['CUST_ID','tx_code']).agg({'TRAN_AMT':sum})

ddf = ddf[ddf.tx_code=='SLIP']

df = ddf.compute()
```

Giving me error on third operation by saying
`DataFrame` object has no attribute `tx_code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `groupby().agg()`, you will generally get a dataframe back which has the grouping column entries as the index, and not the columns. This is the same behaviour as for pandas. If you want to select one as a column, you can do `df.reset_index()`, or you could refer directly to the index; in this case I would prefer the former, because multi-indexes are hard to work with:

```
ddf['tx_code'] = ddf.apply(setTxCode,axis=1)

ddf = ddf.groupby(['CUST_ID','tx_code']).agg({'TRAN_AMT':sum}).reset_index()

ddf = ddf[ddf.tx_code=='SLIP]

df = ddf.compute()
```

Comment: Does `reset_index` trigger a computation in dask? If so, it may be something OP may wish to avoid before the subsequent filter.

Comment: It does not. *Setting* an index may.

Comment: @mdurant  solution has worked. It is the index problem